# texlive on Mac: how do I "switch repository" as message says

Tags: texlive

I run OS 10.10.5 on Macs. I have teX Live Utility version 1.21. When I run it I get a window that says :Repository has a different TeX Live version, The repository at http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet has TeX Live 2015, but you have TeX Live 2014 installed.  You need to switch repositories in order to continue."  I do not know what this means. What do I do? How do I "switch repositories"?

Comment: It means that updates for TeX Live 2014 are no longer available on CTAN. What version of TeX Live Utility are you using? It should automatically switch to the backup repository for TL 2014 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your repositories with Configure > Manage Repositories.

Note that one can only update to TeX Live 2015 (which is highly recommended, as it contains many improvements) by downloading a fresh installation of [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: Under Configure > Manage Repositories only the URLs to different download sites can be managed, none of which indicate that they would be only for the updated TexLive version?